# Find the likelihood function of $f(x)=e^{-(x-a) - e^{-(x-a)}}$

Tags: statistics, maximum-likelihood

> Find the likelihood function of $f(x)=e^{-(x-a)- e^{-(x-a)}}$

I know the definition and I know it should look like $$\mathcal L(a)=f(x_1\mid a)\dots f(x_n\mid a)$$ but I'm lost with the exponential calculation, can someone show me the likelihood function of this thing? I got it like $$\mathcal L(a)=\exp\left\{{-\sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i-a-e^{-\sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i-a}}\right\}$$ can it be simplier?

Comment: Is $x\ge a$ or $x>0$?

Comment: @JimmyR. I actually need to find the most powerful test for $H_0:a=0$ v.s $H_A:a=a_1$ where $a_1>0$